# send mail from command line ubuntu

Tags: email

I'm trying to send email from the command line in ubuntu so that I can incorporate it into my script.

When I run this command:

```
echo "This is a test email again"| sendmail tdunphy@mycompany.com
```

I see this in the mail logs:

```
Jul  9 13:41:21 tdunphy-VirtualBox postfix/local[31388]: B8BF17F: to=<tdunphy@mycompany.com>, relay=local, delay=0.17, delays=0.1/0.04/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Jul  9 13:41:21 tdunphy-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[31307]: B8BF17F: removed
```

But for some reason the email never arrives. Any tips on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks to be more of a server config question than a programming question - you may have more luck on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I am not using a mail server. We have an open relay. I should be able to use that.